# Show only data between dates in excel chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, charts

I have yearly net profit data that uses spill formulas in Columns A and B and in columns D and E I have used start and end date selectors in G2 and I2 to gather the subset of data for the chart.

The chart data has the Net Profit data range set to `='Yearly Net Profit'!$E$2:$E$35` and the years are set to `='Yearly Net Profit'!$D$2:$D$35`.

As you can see from the image below, the chart graphs all the blank space from D10 onwards which I don't want.

[image: Net Profit Chart]

I tried using `='Yearly Net Profit'!$E$2#` but unfortunately it doesn't like this.

I then added two entries in to the Name Manager, one for **YearsForYearlyNetProfitFiltered** set to `='Yearly Net Profit'!$D$2#` and the second **YearyNetProfitFiltered** set to `='Yearly Net Profit'!$E$2#`.

I re-selected the data for the chart, so Net Profit data became `='Yearly Net Profit'!YearyNetProfitFiltered` and the Years became `='Yearly Net Profit'!YearsForYearlyNetProfitFiltered`.

Unfortunately this results in only one entry being visible, see image below:

[image]

You'll see in cells N and O I have output the named ranges. Why would the named ranges only have one entry?

Comment: You need to use a formula like I have shown below. Otherwise it won't work. It won't create the requisite range. `INDEX():INDEX()` when used to return a reference and not a value, the use of full lookup then the colon, then another full lookup gives Excel the hint it needs that it must return a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you are looking to create a **dynamic chart** or not, but you may try to follow the steps as is mentioned.

[image]

---

**A Quick Gif on the dynamic chart**

[image]

---

**Steps:**

1. Select the data, and from `Insert` Tab --> Under `Charts` Group --> Click `Insert Column Or Bar Chart` --> Select `2D Clustered Column`
2. Now, create two formulas one for the `YEAR` and another for the `NETPROFIT`

---

• Formula for `YEAR`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$24,MATCH($D$2,$A$2:$A$24,0)):INDEX($A$2:$A$24,MATCH($F$2,$A$2:$A$24,0))
```

---

• Formula for `NETPROFIT`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$24,MATCH($D$2,$A$2:$A$24,0)):INDEX($B$2:$B$24,MATCH($F$2,$A$2:$A$24,0))
```

---

3. Copy the formulas and place in `Name Manager` by defining the respective names for each. Like as below:

[image]

4. Next, select the chart, `Chart Design` --> `Select Data`
5. Under `Legend Entries Series`, Click On the Series of `Net Profit` --> Click `Edit`, a new window opens as `Edit Series`

[image]

6. In `Series Values` remove everything except the sheet name and press `F3` (Function Key) and select **NETPROFIT** from `Paste Names`

[image]

7. Like wise from `Horizontal (Category Axis Labels)` click on edit and do the same as above in bullet 6

[image]

8. Press Ok, to return back to Excel. Change the `Start Year` & `End Year` to see the changes you need it will show only the data from the range of years shown in the cells `D2` & `F2`.

---

**Note:** I have used `Millions` as display units for `Y-Axis`. Here is a copy of the **[workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ciU76aURcyaIiIGvU?e=KMuK5a)**

---

Comment: Instead of using formula using a slicer might be even simpler