# Dynamic sheet reference for chart legend value in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, charts

When a new project starts we have a button in an excel workbook that creates a Project P&L sheet and now an associated chart sheet to display the Net Profit and Project costing graphs as below.

[image: Charts]

To ensure the chart is dynamic and within the dates set out in **C2** and **E2** I've used Named Ranges for all the Legend Entries as per my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146291/show-only-data-between-dates-in-excel-chart?noredirect=1#comment132611314_75146291). An example named range I've used :

**ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged** refers to the following: `=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&'Project 1 Charts'!$A$2&"'!I15#"),MATCH('Project 1 Charts'!$C$2, INDIRECT("'"&'Project 1 Charts'!$A$2&"'!I1#"))):INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&'Project 1 Charts'!$A$2&"'!I15#"),MATCH('Project 1 Charts'!$E$2, INDIRECT("'"&'Project 1 Charts'!$A$2&"'!I1#")))` and is scoped for the **Project 1 Charts** sheet.

This all works great for Project 1. However, when I duplicate **Project 1 Charts** sheet and rename to **Project 2 Charts** it copies the named ranges correctly, scoping them for the **Project 2 Charts** sheet, but the Legend Entries in the charts on the new sheet point to Project 1, for example the Net Profit in the first chart has the following for Series Values: `='Project 1 Charts'!ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged`.

If I manually change the Series Value to `='Project 2 Charts'!ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged` it grabs the correct data from the **Project 2** sheet.

I wondered whether I could change the `'Project 2 Charts'!` part of the Series Value by having the sheet name in a cell. To test this I inserted  `=MID(CELL("filename",H1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",H1))+1,255)` into B2 giving **Project 2 Charts**. I then tested this by sticking a random number in cell C25 and using  `=INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!C25")` to grab it which it did.

I then tried to switch C2 out for the Named Range **ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged** giving `=INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged")` in the hope that I could then use this in the Chart Legend entries but I get a Ref error. If I paste the following in to a cell `='Project 2 Charts'!ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged` it gives me the correct results.

Is there a way to make my experiements work or is there an alternative way I can duplicate **Project 1 Charts** and it correctly fixes up the Chart Legend entries?

Or is this going to require a VBA solution? Ideally it wouldn't but if it's the only way it could work for me.

Comment: Without having tested it myself: what happens if you create a new blank excel workbook and then, instead of "move and copy" the sheet within the same workbook, you copy it to the new workbook, rename it there, and then move it back to the original?

Comment: ended up creating a macro to run through and fix the paths up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the project P&L and the associated chart sheet is created via code, I used the following macro to fix up the paths, where **ChartSheetString** is the name of the newly created chart sheet.

For example, for a project with the name **Project 2**, a **Project 2 Charts** sheet is created through copying the **Project Template Charts** sheet. This correctly creates scoped named ranges for the sheet but gives various Series Values with paths `='Project Template Charts'!ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged` etc. Meaning it'll end up referencing the named ranges associated with the **Project Template Charts** sheet, as noted in the question.

To fix the paths, I pass the name of the chart sheet in to the FixChartPaths function which will loop through all the Series Values and fix them up, for instance, our example becomes `='Project 2 Charts'!ProjectTemplateNetProfitRanged`

```
Sub FixChartPaths(ChartSheetString As String)
    Dim Wb As Workbook: Set Wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim ChartTemplateSheetString As String
    ChartTemplateSheetString = "Project Template Charts"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    If Wb.WorkSheetExists(ChartSheetString, Wb) Then
        
        Dim Sh As Worksheet
        Set Sh = Wb.Worksheets(ChartSheetString)
        
        Dim cht As ChartObject
        
        For Each cht In Sh.ChartObjects
            
            'MsgBox cht.Name
            Debug.Print cht.Name
            Dim mySrs As Series
            
            'Loop through all series
            For Each mySrs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
                
                'Debug.Print mySrs.Formula
                
                'Replace sheet name in formula
                Dim strTemp As String
                strTemp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(mySrs.Formula, ChartTemplateSheetString, ChartSheetString)
                'Debug.Print strTemp
                mySrs.Formula = strTemp
                
                'Debug.Print mySrs.Formula
            Next
  
        Next cht

        Sh.Range("A1").Select
        
    End If
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```